# Bucketing data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am starting with data that looks like this:

```
+----------+------------------+--------+
| specimen |       date       | bucket |
+----------+------------------+--------+
| 31598D   | 3/3/2010 11:38   |     10 |
| A113899  | 2/10/2010 13:50  |     11 |
| A121375  | 12/17/2010 10:06 |      2 |
| A122115  | 6/14/2010 9:33   |     10 |
| A122119  | 5/19/2010 10:08  |      3 |
| A122124  | 6/30/2010 11:43  |      4 |
| DD58834  | 6/17/2010 10:08  |      1 |
| 31598A   | 3/3/2010 11:36   |     10 |
+----------+------------------+--------+
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to transform it to a frequency distribution like this:

[image]

Would I use the `pivot` function in SQL Server? If so, how?

Please note that I do have access to SSRS, and can use that as a resource to tackle this challenge.

Thanks so much for your guidance and time

Comment: @marc_s can you please help wiht this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711220/outputting-full-sequential-range-of-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, as I don't have a SQL Server instance handy, but it should illustrate the idea; you can SUM() over a case statement to generate the distribution you want.

```
SELECT
      [bucket]
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,[date]) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS [Jan]
    -- repeat the above for each month
FROM
    [your_table]
GROUP BY
    [bucket]
ORDER BY
    [bucket] DESC
```

Comment: can you please help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711220/outputting-full-sequential-range-of-values

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH    bm (maxbucket) AS
        (
        SELECT  MAX(bucket)
        FROM    mydata
        ),
        buckets (bucket) AS
        (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  bucket + 1
        FROM    buckets
        JOIN    bm
        ON      bucket < maxbucket
        )
SELECT  bucket, p.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  b.bucket, DATEPART(month, dt) AS mon
        FROM    buckets b
        LEFT JOIN
                mydata m
        ON      m.bucket = b.bucket
        ) q
PIVOT   (
        COUNT(mon)
        FOR
        mon IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
        ) p
```

Comment: thank you so much. i'm executing this statement right now and it' s taking a while. this is actually pulling data from a view. is it possible to have indexes on a view?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: depends on view definition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms191432.aspx

Comment: cool. this has been running for 15 minutes and still no results, can you suggest to me what i can do to speed it up?

Comment: or do you think perhaps it woudl be better to let SSRS handle the pivot and just feed ssrs the view?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: I can't tell without seeing the view definition. Just try both ways.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: Also, you can try materializing `buckets` into a table variable, recursive `CTE` can yield peculiar plans.

Comment: can you please help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711220/outputting-full-sequential-range-of-values

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from t
pivot (
        count (*) for datepart(m, date) 
        in ([01],[02],[03],[04],[05],
            [06],[07],[08],[09],[10],[11],[12])
) as CountSpec
```

try that

Comment: You will be missing the bucket numbers that don't exist in the table.

Comment: change it to count(bucket) for instance

Comment: can you please help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711220/outputting-full-sequential-range-of-values