# outputting full sequential range of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a sql query:

```
  SELECT
  TAT,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) JAN,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FEB,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MAR,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) APR,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MAY,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) JUN,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) JUL,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AUG,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) SEP,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OCT,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NOV,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [DEC]

  FROM
  [SalesDWH].[dbo].[TurnAround]
  where DATEPART(yyyy,[datetime entered])=2010
  GROUP BY TAT
  ORDER BY 1;
```

here's what it returns:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| TAT | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   3 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|   7 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  18 |  28 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  19 |  39 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |  53 |   0 |   0 |
|  20 | 106 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   2 |  17 |   0 |   1 |   2 |   0 |
|  21 | 113 |  12 |   0 |   0 |   0 |  22 |   1 |  81 | 137 |  27 |   1 | 110 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

i would like the output to be:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| TAT | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   0 |     |     |     |   3 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   1 |   1 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   2 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   3 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   4 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   5 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   6 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   7 |     |     |     |     |   1 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   8 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|   9 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  10 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  11 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  12 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  13 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  14 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  15 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  16 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  17 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  18 |  28 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|  19 |  39 |     |     |     |     |   1 |     |     |     |  53 |     |     |
|  20 | 106 |     |     |     |     |     |   2 |  17 |     |   1 |   2 |     |
|  21 | 113 |  12 |     |     |     |  22 |   1 |  81 | 137 |  27 |   1 | 110 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

please notice that all `0`'s have been removed and that the `TAT` column is sequential 0,1,2,3,4,......

**how do i force these two conditions**?

i need this for values of TAT between 0 and 191.

**for values 192 and greater, i would like the TAT at 192 to be a sum of all values of 192 and greater**

Comment: Is the range always 0-21 or is it 0-MAX(TAT)?

Comment: so create a table that stores all possible values

Comment: Note that you can use `PIVOT` to avoid your complex `CASE` expressions.

Comment: @vittore you don't need to store a table with 192 rows to generate contiguous numbers from 0-191.

Comment: i'm sorry  the highest is 20000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** for new info

```
;WITH d AS ( SELECT TAT = CASE WHEN TAT > 191 THEN 192 ELSE TAT END,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS JAN,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 2  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FEB,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 3  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAR,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 4  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APR,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 5  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAY,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 6  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS JUN,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS JUL,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 8  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AUG,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 9  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SEP,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OCT,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NOV,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month Entered] = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DEC
  FROM [SalesDWH].[dbo].[TurnAround]
  WHERE [datetime entered] >= '20100101'
    AND [datetime entered] <  '20110101'
  GROUP BY CASE WHEN TAT > 191 THEN 192 ELSE TAT END
),
n AS ( SELECT TOP (193) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
  FROM sys.all_columns ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT TAT = n.n,
  JAN = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(JAN, 0)), ''),
  FEB = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(FEB, 0)), ''),
  MAR = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(MAR, 0)), ''),
  APR = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(APR, 0)), ''),
  MAY = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(MAY, 0)), ''),
  JUN = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(JUN, 0)), ''),
  JUL = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(JUL, 0)), ''),
  AUG = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(AUG, 0)), ''),
  SEP = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(SEP, 0)), ''),
  OCT = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(OCT, 0)), ''),
  NOV = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(NOV, 0)), ''),
  DEC = COALESCE(RTRIM(NULLIF(DEC, 0)), '')
FROM n LEFT OUTER JOIN d ON n.n = d.TAT 
ORDER BY n.n; -- do not use ordinal numbers for ORDER BY!
```

Comment: for some reason it grabbed only 123 results

Comment: one more question, for everything at 192 and greater, can the entire row just be the SUM of all values greater and equal to 192

Comment: wow amazing thanks so much. how does it know to SUM everything at 192+?

Comment: Because it's grouped that way. Every value of TAT > 191 is replaced with 192.

Comment: awesome.except i dont think it is summing , it's just stopping at 191

Comment: works amazingly well!! just one issue is that it is summing 193+ instead of 192+

Comment: Don't know how that's possible unless you didn't copy that line correctly (the highest value of n that will come out of the numbers cte is 192, unless you left off the -1).

Answer (score 1):

first, you need create a table with all values for your first column and join data table with it

then you do another query on top of this one ( so this one is subquery) and each month column will be

```
 case jan when 0 then '' else cast(jan as nvarchar) end jan
```